# How to tweak a bibliography style created with the makebst utility?

Tags: custom-bib

I want to prepare the following reference:

> Doroszkowski A (1999) The physical chemistry of dispersion. In: Lambourne
> E, Strivens TA (eds.) Paint and surface coatings: Theory and practice.
> Woodhead Publishing Limited, Cambridge, pp. 198–242

However, when I use `makebst` the word "In" appears as "in".

I wonder how I can get the letter `i` in the word "in" capitalized.

Comment: in the bst file you generated will appear the literal string "in" just change it to In

Comment: Thanks a lot David!

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you are fine with the other settings embedded in your bespoke bst file and hence would prefer not to re-run the `makebst` utility from scratch. If that's the case, I think the simplest solution to your formatting question is as follows. First, open the bst file in a text editor. Then, search for the following code block:

```
FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }
```

Change it to

```
FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "In" }
```

and save the bst file.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Mico!